# custom checkbox have jerking with its postioning

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have tried checkbox like functionalities with jQuery and CSS. But while clicking on checkbox, some jerking in position of checkbox. You can find the jsfiddle in [here](https://jsfiddle.net/zrcza9g5/), in here I have defined `display: inline-block` for that `span` element.

But the same is working when I define `display: block`, I don't know get why that jerking comes with inline-block. JSfiddle link in [here](https://jsfiddle.net/zrcza9g5/3/).

```
<span name="list4_wrap"  id="check4wrap" class=" e-checkwrap"></span>
 #css
 .e-checkwrap {
        border: 1px solid;
        height: 14px;
        width: 14px;
        display: block;
        border-color: #c8c8c8;
        background-color: #fff;
        cursor: pointer;
            font-size: 12px;   

    }
    .e-check-act:before {
        content: "a";
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        color: #179bd7;

        text-indent: 1px;
    }
#JS
$("#check4wrap").click(function(e){
    var curEle = e.target.nodeName === "INPUT" ? e.target.parentElement : e.target;
        if (curEle.className.indexOf("e-check-act") < 0) {
            curEle.className += " e-check-act";               
        }
        else {
            curEle.className = curEle.className.replace("e-check-act", " ");               
        }
});
```

Please give some suggestion on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you're appending text before **.e-check-act**
which changes it's position.

Set `.e-check-act:before { position:absolute; }` and it stays in place.